# How to use a string description to access data from a hash-within-hash structure?

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
data_spec['data'] = "some.awesome.values"

data_path = ""
data_spec['data'].split('.').each do |level|
  data_path = "#{data_path}['#{level}']"
end

data = "site.data#{data_path}"
```

At this point, `data` equals a string: `"site.data['some']['awesome']['values']"`

What I need help with is using the string to get the value of: `site.data['some']['awesome']['values']`

`site.data` has the following value:

```
{  
    "some" => {  
        "awesome" => {  
            "values" => [  
                {  
                    "things" => "Stuff",
                    "stuff" => "Things",
                },
                {  
                    "more_things" => "More Stuff",
                    "more_stuff" => "More Things",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could use an `eval`, but that's not really a good way to go about it. Is your actual problem to return value `site.data['some']['awesome']['values']` given the input string `"some.awesome.values"` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, I'm very new to Ruby. The data_spec['data'] is being pulled from a YAML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do as tadman suggested and use `site.data.dig('some', 'awesome', values')` if you are using ruby 2.3.0 (which is awesome and I didn't even know existed). This is probably your best choice. But if you really want to write the code yourself read below.

You were on the right track, the best way to do this is:

```
data_spec['data'] = "some.awesome.values"

data = nil
data_spec['data'].split('.').each do |level|
  if data.nil?
    data = site.data[level]
  else
    data = data[level]
  end
end
```

To understand why this works first you need to understand that `site.data['some']['awesome']['values']` is the same as saying: first get `some` then inside that get `awesome` then inside that get `values`. So our first step is retrieving the `some`. Since we don't have that first level yet we get it from `site.data` and save it to a variable `data`. Once we have that we just get each level after that from data and save it to data, allowing us to get deeper and deeper into the hash.

So using your example `data` would initally look like this:

```
        {"awesome" => {  
            "values" => [  
                {  
                    "things" => "Stuff",
                    "stuff" => "Things",
                },
                {  
                    "more_things" => "More Stuff",
                    "more_stuff" => "More Things",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Then this:

```
        {"values" => [  
            {  
                "things" => "Stuff",
                "stuff" => "Things",
            },
            {  
                "more_things" => "More Stuff",
                "more_stuff" => "More Things",
            }
        ]
    }
```

and finally output like this:

```
        [  
            {  
                "things" => "Stuff",
                "stuff" => "Things",
            },
            {  
                "more_things" => "More Stuff",
                "more_stuff" => "More Things",
            }
        ]
```

Comment: This is on the right track. If the original string format of `x['y']['z']` needs to be handled, that will require a regular expression of some sort presumably.

Comment: I don't think one is needed as long as OP plans to use the format of 'foo.bar.foobar' and splits on .

Comment: This solution works for a single level `"some"`. I am getting an error.`Error:  no implicit conversion of String into Integer` when I try to use `"some.awesome"`

Comment: @KyleBrumm It sounds like you're hitting an array. Is `some` an array or a hash? (does it have [] or {})

Comment: I believe it is a hash. Sorry, I'm very new to Ruby.

Comment: Yeah, if its an array then you will need to pick one of the values using a number. My solution assumes you have nested hashes only, or at least that it ends with an array.

Comment: Awesome this did it. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

If you're receiving a string like `'x.y.z'` and need to navigate a nested hash, Ruby 2.3.0 includes the [`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method:

```
spec = "some.awesome.values"

data = {  
  "some" => {  
    "awesome" => {  
        "values" => [
          'a','b','c'
        ]
    }
  }
}

data.dig(*spec.split('.'))
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

If you don't have Ruby 2.3.0 and upgrading isn't an option you can just patch it in for now:

```
class Hash
  def dig(*path)
    path.inject(self) do |location, key|
      location.respond_to?(:keys) ? location[key] : nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something that does exactly this.  Feel free to take any information of value from it or steal it! :)

https://github.com/keithrbennett/trick_bag/blob/master/lib/trick_bag/collections/collection_access.rb

Check out the unit tests to see how to use it:

https://github.com/keithrbennett/trick_bag/blob/master/spec/trick_bag/collections/collection_access_spec.rb

There's an `accessor` method that returns a lambda.  Since lambdas can be called using the `[]` operator (method, really), you can get such a lambda and access arbitrary numbers of levels:

```
accessor['hostname.ip_addresses.0']
```

or, in your case:

```
require 'trick_bag'
accessor = TrickBag::CollectionsAccess.accessor(site.data)
do_something_with(accessor['some.awesome.values'])
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is something generally looked down upon and for good reasons. But here you go - it's called [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval):

```
binding.eval data
```

Comment: This is complete over-kill and is a broken solution you should be ashamed to suggest. There's a *reason* this is looked down on.

Comment: @Ilya as if I didn't mention it. It's just the correct answer of the question *"I have this `data` variable, how do I get the code inside executed"*.

Comment: This is a data navigation problem best solved without arbitrary code execution.

Comment: @tadman this is not how to read the question. OP has constructed the variable for a reason. It didn't ask *"how do I fix my code"* it asked *" given this, how do I evaluate it"*.

Comment: You often have to read between the lines on a question and figure out what the actual intent is. `eval` is an **absolute last resort** and should be avoided whenever possible. This is not a case where `eval` is strictly necessary. It's not even close.

Comment: @tadman reading between the lines is not answering a different question just because you don't like the actual answer.

Comment: @ndn, i think it is really very obvious and danger solution. You should not advice it

Comment: @tadman seriously, read the title even. It asks for `eval` in the most straight forward easy possible.

Comment: You're suggesting something that would be an automatic fail in any code review I'd ever do and I'm not alone here. This is a completely inappropriate use of `eval`. I don't know why you're fighting so hard here. Casual use of `eval` in situations like this is why CERT advisories are issued. Ruby had a few of these related to the YAML and XML parser modules which executed arbitrary code for reasons nobody could explain. Don't even go down this road to start with.

Comment: @tadman ffs, I never said it was a good idea to use eval to fetch data from yml files, I'm simply saying that anything short of eval or writing a parser yourself doesn't answer the question that was being asked.

Comment: The inclination of some people to construct non existing strawmans and proceed pitchforking them is outstanding.

Comment: @ndn If anyone's pitchforking here it's you and your bizarre crusade to justify using `eval` here.

Comment: @tadman interesting... Who was the person I was pitchforking?

Comment: @tadman how am I justifying it, given my very answer started with "it's not a good idea"